# Where did i make a mistake in my program i think its a logical error but i cant quite find it

Tags: c

I have this program that I wrote, it complies but I don't think it outputs correctly. Did I make a mistake here?
Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int loop_counter = -8;
    int user_input = 9;
    char c1 = '9';
    char c2 = 43;

    while(loop_counter != 21);
    {
        printf("%d\n", loop_counter);
        printf("%d\n", loop_counter+1);
        printf("%d\n", loop_counter+2);

        loop_counter = loop_counter + 1;
        loop_counter++;

        printf("%d\n", loop_counter);
        printf("%d\n", loop_counter+1);
        printf("%d\n", loop_counter+2);

        getchar();
    }

    printf("loop exit\n\n");    
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: What output do you get, and what output do you expect?

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: How can someone tell you if it outputs what it's supposed to if we don't know the expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: You increment the loop counter twice in a row, in two different ways, which seems a bit odd.

Comment: okay sorry thee misunderstanding the loop doesn't and i think its a logic error in some of the lines but i cant quite find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest error is

```
while(loop_counter != 21);
```

where the trailing `;` will make the loop infinite.

Comment: Correct but the loop still doesn't exit

Comment: That is because the loop counter is always even, as you increment it twice in every loop as commented above. Did you correct that already?

Comment: Ive corrected the while(loop_counter != 21); by removing the semi colon so by removing the  increment  the loop will exit ?

Comment: You must remove the *double* increment. Either `loop_counter = loop_counter + 1;` or `loop_counter++;` but not both.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is probably that you have not articulated what you are hoping the code will do or what you intended the code to do or what you think it does. I am assuming you just need some help so my attempt to do so is below.

Running this through the compiler and interpreting the error messages helps a little.
Right off the bat, the compiler doesn't like your call to main. The compiler offers a suggestion that will successfully fix this error, so just follow the advice (and don't forget to add a 
return 0; 
statement before you exit main. 
Second warning the compiler generates is that you have a semicolon at the end of your while statement. It also tells you how to fix it. Follow the instructions and you should be able to generate an executable.

You will still, however, have problems at runtime. This gets back to what is your intent. 
With errors above corrected, your loop_counter variable enters the while loop initialized to -8, increases by 1 on line 19 and again increases by 1 on line 20. A call is made to getchar() but no input is given. Also lines 7, 8, and 9 are not used by your program.

Hope this gives you some direction. :)

Comment: Note that `main` is an exception in that is not required to return any value for its `int`.